# Read a text file and remove all characters except alphabets & spaces in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove all characters except alphabets along with the spaces. 
This is what my code looks like. 
Where sampletext.txt contains words with multiple characters, I am writing the result in removed.txt.
When I run this code. I am getting only blanks in removed.txt

```
import re
import sys
filename = open("removed.txt",'w')
sys.stdout = filename
from string import ascii_letters
allowed = set(ascii_letters + ' ')
with open("/Desktop/stem_analysis/sampletext.txt", 'r') as f:
    answer = ''.join(l for l in f if l in allowed)
print(answer)
```

Whats the problem with my code

Comment: your current logic is sound but the way you write output is odd, try `with open("/Desktop/stem_analysis/sampletext.txt", 'r') as f, open('removed.txt', 'w') as out_f: out_f.write(''.join(l for l in f if l in allowed.read()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to remove all characters except alphabets along with the
>   spaces.

I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to do, but to remove *all characters except alphabets along with the spaces*, you can use something like:

```
with open("old_file.txt", "r") as f, open("new_file.txt", "w") as n:
    x = f.read()
    result = re.sub("[^a-z\s]", "", x, 0, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
    n.write(result)
```

---

**Regex Explanation:**

[image]

---

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ReO40k/1)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the characters that are not in the alphabet. Add another if statement to check for spaces.

```
def letters(input):
  return ''.join([c for c in input if (c.isalpha()==False)])
```

Comment: simply `''.join(c for c in my_input if not c.isalpha())` ;  `input()` is a function name so don't shadow it

Comment: moreover they actually want to *keep* alphabet chars (and spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

import re
re.sub(r'^[a-zA-Z]', '', your_string)

should do what you’re asking except for the spaces part. I’m sure you can figure out how to add that in to the regex as well.